# Scala 3 extension overloading with different generic types

Tags: scala, extension-methods, implicit, scala-3

I'm migrating from Scala 2.13 to Scala 3 and I'm trying to rewrite small utility functions. In 2.13 it was possible to write one more generic implicit and another one more specific but in Scala 3 it seems no longer possible.

```scala
  type Outcome[+E <: Fail, A] = Either[E, A]

  extension[A] (list: List[Outcome[ValidationFail, A]]) {
    def outcomeListAll: Outcome[ValidationFail, List[A]] = {
      val (left, right) = list.partitionOutcome
      if (left.isEmpty) {
        Right(right)
      } else {
        Left(left.reduce(_ + _))
      }
    }
  }

  extension[F <: Fail, A] (list: List[Outcome[F, A]])
    @deprecated
    def outcomeListAll: Outcome[Fail, List[A]] = {
      val (left, right) = partitionOutcome
      if (left.isEmpty) {
        Right(right)
      } else {
        Left(Fail.generic(left.map(_.getMessage).mkString(", "), left.head))
      }
    }
    def partitionOutcome: (List[F], List[A]) = {
      val left: List[F] = list.collect {
        case Left(l) => l
      }
      val right: List[A] = list.collect {
        case Right(r) => r
      }
      (left, right)
    }
```

When I try compiling above code snippet I get double definition error. Which at least according to [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html) article should resolve to methods with different signatures. Like so:

```scala
<extension> def < (x: String)(y: String): Boolean = ...
<extension> def +: (xs: Seq[Elem])(x: Elem): Seq[Elem] = ...
<extension> infix def min(x: Number)(y: Number): Number = ...
```

I know I can simply use pattern matching but it seems odd that I can't overload extensions like you could with methods.

Compilation error:

```
[error] -- [E120] Naming Error: /home/...testing/Main.scala:19:8 
[error] 19 |    def outcomeListAll: Outcome[Fail, List[A]] = {
[error]    |        ^
[error]    |Double definition:
[error]    |def outcomeListAll(list: scala.collection.immutable.List): scala.util.Either in object Main at line 7 and
[error]    |def outcomeListAll(list: scala.collection.immutable.List): scala.util.Either in object Main at line 19
[error]    |have the same type after erasure.
[error]    |
[error]    |Consider adding a @targetName annotation to one of the conflicting definitions
[error]    |for disambiguation.
```

Comment: You should be able to use `@scala.annotation.targetName("someothername")` to avoid the double definition error, I think. Where exactly are you getting the error, and what does it say?

Comment: I completely overlooked that compiler suggestion to use annotation. It work thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could post an answer to your question showing the update to the code; in this case including the annotation. This would serve as great documentation for those having the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508981/scala-3-extension-overloading-with-different-generic-types?noredirect=1#comment122859332_69508981) pointed out, problem can be solved by using annotation `@targetName("...")`

```
  import scala.annotation.targetName

  type Outcome[+E <: Fail, A] = Either[E, A]

  extension[A] (list: List[Outcome[ValidationFail, A]]) {
    @targetName("outcomeListAllForValidationFail")
    def outcomeListAll: Outcome[ValidationFail, List[A]] = {
      val (left, right) = list.partitionOutcome
      if (left.isEmpty) {
        Right(right)
      } else {
        Left(left.reduce(_ + _))
      }
    }
  }

  extension[F <: Fail, A] (list: List[Outcome[F, A]])
    def outcomeListAll: Outcome[Fail, List[A]] = {
      val (left, right) = partitionOutcome
      if (left.isEmpty) {
        Right(right)
      } else {
        Left(Fail.generic(left.map(_.getMessage).mkString(", "), left.head))
      }
    }
    def partitionOutcome: (List[F], List[A]) = {
      val left: List[F] = list.collect {
        case Left(l) => l
      }
      val right: List[A] = list.collect {
        case Right(r) => r
      }
      (left, right)
    }
```